# Error in Compiling Java code

Tags: java, android, debugging

I cant find how to remove the errors in the code below

```
package com.example.hellocodelearn;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hellocodelearn.models.Notes;


 public class NotesListActivity extends ListActivity 

{

    private ArrayAdapter NotesItemArrayAdapter ;
    private List<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<Notes>() ; 

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) 
    {
        Notes tweet = new Notes();
        tweet.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " +i);
        tweet.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " +i);
        notes.add(tweet);
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_list);

      NotesItemArrayAdapter = new NotesAdapter(this, new String[10]);
      setListAdapter(NotesItemArrayAdapter);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotesDetailActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
 }


}
```

I get errors :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   NotesListActivity.java  /HelloCodeLearn/src/com/example/hellocodelearn  line 47 Java Problem
```

Pleas help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a for loop in the body of your class, it has to go inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop should be in a method rather than in the class block

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
      ....
    }
}
```